# Automatically update database when new excel sheet is added in a folder

Tags: java, excel, db2

I need to write one java program which monitors a folder containing excel sheets (.xls format) . Once a new excel sheet is added I have to update the database in db2 and move the excel sheet to other place.
Please suggest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need to get notified if files appear in a directory. Java 7 has good support for this, see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) article about the Watch Service API. The db2 part, well it isn't clear what you mean by "update", but likely you want to parse the content of the xls file and make some database updates. [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) is a good starting place for reading the content of the file into a Java process.

Comment: By Update i mean - There is a database in db2. I have to "add" (data keeps on increasing as new excel sheet is loaded in the directory) the data from the excel sheet to the database.

Comment: OK, the above still stands. You are going to need to read in the context of the xls file (e.g. with Apache POI), locate the required data by navigating the rows and columns (that are now java objects) and then insert into the database, likely via JDBC. So, in summary, there are three things you need to understand (or learn): 1. how to notice there is a new file (file watcher or directory polling), 2. how to read the file (Apache POI), 3. how to save the data to DB2 (JDBC).